# SendGrid - Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

I've been using SendGrid for a long time and it was functioning well until the error below appeared.

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity
```

My Laravel app sends emails from many 'from' addresses. For instance,

```
info@example.com
asfand@exacmple.com
john@example.com
```

It was functioning, but on April 25th, 2023, it abruptly stopped working for all 'from' email addresses except `info@example.com`; it is still working for 'info@example.com', no code has been updated, and nothing has been changed in SendGrid.

I tried every solution on stackoverflow, but none of them worked.